# C# wpf datagrid editable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, binding

How do you make a datagrid editable so that users can edit cells of the grid?

Comment: Editable in the sense all the datagrid at once? or Each row at Once?

Comment: each row... I have a button which makes a new row in the datagrid. and know i want to put data in that row

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: DataGrid is editable in .net 4.0. If you don't want to switch to it, install WPF Toolkit.

Comment: DataGrid isn't part of .NET 3.5, even with SP1... It is available in the WPF toolkit

Comment: @Thomas Levesque Are you sure? On this page it says that it is part of the framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: look at the Version Information section: "Supported in: 4". It's been included in 4.0, before that it was only available from the WPF toolkit

Comment: @Thomas Levesque You are right, it is only available in 4.0. I read somewhere that it was in 3.5 sp1, but perhaps I overlooked something...